# Show that if $Y$ hasn't isolated points the graph any function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ has empty interior in $X\times Y$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

My proof:

Suppose that $\operatorname{int}(G(f))\ne \emptyset$. Let $(a,f(a)) \in \operatorname{int}(G(f)) $ then there is an open set $A\times U\subset X\times Y$ such that $(a,f(a)) \in A\times U\subset G(f)$. As $Y$ hasn't isolated points, then there are $y,z \in U$ such that $U$ is an open in $Y$ and $y \ne z$. With this, we have that $(a,y) \in G(f)$ and $(a,z) \in G(f)$. This is a contradiction, because we have 2 different images for a single point.

Is this demonstration correct?

Comment: This looks good to me. I would note that not every open set in $X \times Y$ is of the form $A \times U$, but there is a basis of open sets of this form (so I think you are okay). You may or may not be thinking this, i can't tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks fine, but you could have justified the existenc of $y$ and $z$ such that $y\ne z$ and that $(a,y),(a,z)\in G(f)$. That's easy though: you take $y=f(a)$. Since $\{f(a)\}$ is not open and it is a subset of $U$, which is open, $\{f(a)\}\varsubsetneq U$, and therefore you can take $z\in U\setminus\{f(a)\}$.